# Is there a way to create a compile time warning/error when toString() is being used on nullable variables?

Tags: kotlin, compiler-errors, tostring, nullable

I work with a team that is constantly coercing `String?`s to `String`s using `toString()`.

I have done everything in my power to explain them that doing so is not a really good idea, but I still find that happening.

Is there a plugin, or something that allows me to make the use of `toString()` a wart/warning/error?

Comment: There are various linting solutions available that you could use to combat this. Basically, you want to block use of the extension function https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/to-string.html but leave alone uses of `Any.toString()`.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint is a tool for building analyses like this.  (Despite the name, it's not Android specific.)

Comment: @Tenfour04, indeed. Know of some that covers this specific case?